# What is the correct equivalent of Java of this JS line of code?

Tags: javascript, java

I am trying to lessen the line of codes using the Lambda expression in Java after seeing the same code written in 1 line in JS somewhere. But i am getting this below error:

> Incompatible types.
>   Required:
>   org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntries
>   Found:
>   void

This is what i have now.

```
List e =driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER).getAll();
String s="",t ="";
if (!e.isEmpty()){
                for (Object l : e)
                {
                    t=l.toString();
                    if(t.contains("SyntaxError")){
                        s = s + t+"<BR/>";
                    }
                    else if(t.contains("EvalError")){
                        s = s + t+"<BR/>";
                    }
                    else if(t.contains("ReferenceError")){
                        s = s + t+"<BR/>";
                    }
                    else if(t.contains("RangeError")){
                        s = s + t+"<BR/>";
                    }
                    else if(t.contains("TypeError")){
                        s = s + t+"<BR/>";
                    }
                    else if(t.contains("URIError")){
                        s = s + t+"<BR/>";
                    }
                }
```

And this is what i am trying to get to:

```
List<String > errorStrings = new ArrayList<>();
            errorStrings.add("SyntaxError");
            errorStrings.add("EvalError");
            errorStrings.add("ReferenceError");
            errorStrings.add("RangeError");
            errorStrings.add("TypeError");
            errorStrings.add("URIError");
            LogEntries l = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER).forEach(le -> errorStrings.stream().anyMatch(er -> le.getMessage().contains(er)));
```

By following this line of code written is JS:

```
var jsErrors = Driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser).Where(x => errorStrings.Any(e => x.Message.Contains(e)));
```

Please help me to understand what am i doing wrong.

-TIA

Answer (score 0):

Your code is

```
LogEntries l = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER)
    .forEach(le -> errorStrings.stream()
        .anyMatch(er -> le.getMessage().contains(er)));
```

And your error message is

```
Incompatible types. Required: org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntries Found: void
```

The error message is telling you that your assignment statement is expecting you to return a `LogEntries` but it is getting a `void`. It is getting a `void` because that is the return type of the `Stream.forEach` method. The `forEach` method is used to consume all elements of the stream and return nothing.

I think what you are trying to do is filter a set of log entries and turn them into a `LogEntries` object right? If that's the case I suspect you want `filter` rather than `forEach`.

I'm not a selenium expert so I can't advise you on how to turn a `Stream<LogEntry> into a`LogEntries`. I'm assuming you can use a reduce or collect operation but might be best to pose that as a separate question.

Comment: First of all thanks for your response. filter can only be used to filter the console errors(LogEntries) by their level(eg. Severe, damaging...). But i am trying filter them by the error type(TypeError, SyntaxError). For that it does not have any built in method. So i am trying to use String.contain(charsequence).

Comment: Any idea what would be the equivalent of JS List.where() in Java. I assumed the closest one would be ForEach